# CSS change size of text box with screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I was creating a page on Reactjs. I have two react components, which are basically simple divs. Lets call one LeftPanel and the other one Right Panel.
So for left panel i have float set to left and for the right panel, i have float set to right, so that these panels appear on the respective sides of screen. (see screenshot attached).
[image]

The area left in the center, containing textbox and button is a div with following attributes:

```
.Area{
display: flex;
min-height: 125px;
align-content: center;
background-color: lightblue;
}
```

textarea and button have the following CSS:

```css
.text{
    display: flex;
    width: 55em;
    margin:3% 0% 0% 10%;
    height: 33%;
    font-size: x-large;
    vertical-align: top;
    resize:none;
    border-top-left-radius:30em;
    border-bottom-left-radius:30em;
    border-color:black;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 0px 0px rgb(51, 46, 46);
}

.searchBtn{
    width:20em;
    height: 38%;
    margin-top:3%;
    margin-right:10%;
    border-top-right-radius: 30em;
    border-bottom-right-radius:30em;
    border-color:black;
    outline:none;
    box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px 0px rgb(51, 46, 46);;
}
```

Now, my problem is, that when i reduce the screen size, this happens:
[image]

Below 800px:
[image]

How do i fix this?
I can provide any further information if necessary.

Comment: Hi could you please copy the full html code of your resulting page and put it in codepen or some other online editor and paste link here.

Comment: You have provided width in 'em', please use vw or use media queries to handle different screen sizes. To avoid all these hassles, its better to use frameworks like react-bootstrap, material-ui etc that takes care of these scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid combining flex with float, because output behavior is often unexpectable. In below example I used flex for parent `.container` and for all children. I assume you want `.leftPanel` and `.rightPanel` to have defined `min-width`, so I added `min-width: 250px;` for `.leftPanel` (you can also add it to `.rightPanel`). Property `flex: 1` for all children make them grow so to fit evenly `.container`, but all defined `min-width` are respected.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.leftPanel, .rightPanel, .Area {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.Area{
  display: flex;
  min-height: 125px;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.leftPanel {
  min-width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="leftPanel">
    leftPanel
  </div>
  <div class="Area">
    Area
  </div>
  <div class="rightPanel">
    rightPanel
  </div>
</div>
```